# rails api how to fill headers in request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't understand what I do wrong. I want to send a simple request to an API, and it didn't work:

```rb
    class Paytrace
      require 'rest-client'

      attr_reader :auth_token, :authorize

      def initialize()
        @auth_token = auth_token
      end

      def auth_token
        response = RestClient.post 'https://api.paytrace.com/oauth/token', { grant_type: :password, username: "loginname", password: "htmlkoi8r" }
        puts response
      end

      def authorize
        headers = {:Authorization => "Bearer #{auth_token['access_token']}"}

        response1 = RestClient.get('https://api.paytrace.com/v1/transactions/sale/keyed', headers)

        puts response1
      end
    end

    a = Paytrace.new
    a.authorize
```

> ## console.log
>
> lucker@lucker-pc:~/git/paytrace-testh$ ruby integration.rb 
>   {"access_token":"c6d69786f6075633:8647d6c6b6f6968327:092e8cfc553726d2b8198577ea2836f41173aae68a53aa1d2af2b2c7f65dcdc7","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":7200,"created_at":1556098344}
>   {"access_token":"c6d69786f6075633:8647d6c6b6f6968327:232c92f977a301d033eec321c3d82b73bb65ebec33f9fcc8f6c2d7575c8b0d88","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":7200,"created_at":1556098346}
>   Traceback (most recent call last):    1: from integration.rb:25:in
>   `<main>' integration.rb:16:in`authorize': undefined method `[]' for
>   nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

1. Why is the access_token generated twice?
2. Why is there an undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass?

Comment: a main problem related to  JSON.parse(response). and need to add    require 'json'
 to a head of rb file ( if u run it in an isolate file, not in a rails project). JSON.parse(response) need to add to a bottom of a method for parse to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `auth_token` is not returning a `response`, but a `nil` (`puts` returns `nil`).

Btw, you don't need `attr_reader :authorize` since you have a method with that name.

Also, as you are setting `attr_reader :auth_token`, the method `auth_token` must be rename (and maybe become `private`).

Change your code to:

```rb
    class Paytrace
      require 'rest-client'

      attr_reader :auth_token

      def initialize()
        @auth_token = get_auth_token
      end      

      def authorize
        headers = {:Authorization => "Bearer #{auth_token['access_token']}"}

        RestClient.get('https://api.paytrace.com/v1/transactions/sale/keyed', headers)
      end

      private

        def get_auth_token
          RestClient.post 'https://api.paytrace.com/oauth/token', { grant_type: :password, username: "loginname", password: "htmlkoi8r" }        
        end
    end

    a = Paytrace.new
    puts a.auth_token
    puts a.authorize
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are 3 mistakes in this code the 2 puts. line 12 and 20

and the

```
headers = {:Authorization => "Bearer #{auth_token['access_token']}"}
```

should be

```
headers = {:Authorization => "Bearer #{auth_token[:access_token]}"}
```

or

```
headers = {:Authorization => "Bearer #{@auth_token[:access_token]}"}
```

try this code

```
    class Paytrace
      require 'rest-client'

      attr_reader :auth_token, :authorize

      def initialize()
        @auth_token = auth_token
      end

      def auth_token
        response = RestClient.post 'https://api.paytrace.com/oauth/token', { grant_type: :password, username: "loginname", password: "htmlkoi8r" }
        # puts response
      end

      def authorize
        headers = {:Authorization => "Bearer #{@auth_token[:access_token]}"}

        response1 = RestClient.get('https://api.paytrace.com/v1/transactions/sale/keyed', headers)

        # puts response1
      end
    end

    a = Paytrace.new
    a.authorize
```

take care the your response hash if you check is

```
{:access_token=>"c6d69786f6075633:8647d6c6b6f6968327:092e8cfc553726d2b8198577ea2836f41173aae68a53aa1d2af2b2c7f65dcdc7",
   :token_type=>"Bearer",
   :expires_in=>7200,
   :created_at=>1556098344}
```

and not

```
{"access_token":"c6d69786f6075633:8647d6c6b6f6968327:092e8cfc553726d2b8198577ea2836f41173aae68a53aa1d2af2b2c7f65dcdc7","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":7200,"created_at":1556098344}
```